# RMI, rmic command can'be found and run

Tags: java, rmi

in CMD, im trying to input rmic, but it is error and i am in the right path. I have the stub class too.

```
C:\Users\Tristan\Documents\Verteilte System\Übung_3\RMIServer\RMIServer\bin>ls
MessageInterface.class    MessageServiceImpl_Stub.class
MessageServiceImpl.class  Server.class

C:\Users\Tristan\Documents\Verteilte System\Übung_3\RMIServer\RMIServer\bin>rmic
 MessageServiceImpl
Der Befehl "rmic" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

C:\Users\Tristan\Documents\Verteilte System\Übung_3\RMIServer\RMIServer\bin>
```

Comment: You are using an out of date tutorial.  RMI hasn't needed rmic for many years.

Comment: And you must have succeeded some other time, otherwise where did the existing stub file come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `rmic` is not on the PATH on your Windows installation. In my JDK 1.8 installation `rmic` can be found inside the `bin` directory.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) is a link to the Oracle Java Docs for setting PATH.

Comment: Halo, Stefan.. i think the variable PATH, here is value in my windows :

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin

Comment: Could you please check if `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` points to a JRE or JDK? I think it does not. Usually I would have expected something like this: `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin; etc etc etc
`

Comment: I don't have "rmic" in my bin. I'm using JDK 15.0.2.  I have a similar problem to the OP. What can I do?

Comment: Oracle JDK 15 no longer contains rmic (see https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/15-relnote-issues.html for info on the removal).